# How do I convert a hex string to a signed int value in Java?

Tags: java, casting, hex, decimal, signed

In my computer organization class we were assigned a program. I am stuck on one thing. I have the value 7FF as a string and I need to convert it to a signed int. I can get it to an unsigned int. I get the value 2047. The correct value should be -1.

Right now here is what I have:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("7FF", 16);
```

I have tried casting it with a short but that did not do anything. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Edit: So my main question is, how can I produce an output of -1 with the hex string "7FF"?

Comment: Java doesn't have unsigned ints. Why would it return -1? It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: @shmosel I understand that. We have to read in hex values from a file. We have to use those values in the program and they need to be signed values. So while I know java does not have that feature I am trying to find a way to make it work. I need it to be able to produce a -1 from that number.

Comment: Java certainly does have signed values. And you still haven't explained why it would evaluate to -1.

Comment: It looks like the assignment is to understand two's complement arithmetic, not use Java builtins.

Comment: @shmosel 7FF in binary is 11111111111 . Using 2's complement that equals -1 in decimal.

Comment: @jkinkead I understand how to do 2's complement (I took a semester on assembly language) I am just seeing if there is a better way to convert the number to a signed decimal.

Comment: @KeenanKaufman only on an 11 bit machine.

Comment: There are no built-in data types that are 11 bits long. You would have to write that logic yourself.

Comment: What about right-shifting the hex literal by an appropriate amount?

Comment: @KeenanKaufman You said you tried casting to `short`, but a `short` is 16 bits, and `7FF` as a `short` is `0000 0111 1111 1111`. Since the first bit is `0`, it's a positive number. Only way for `7FF` to be `-1` is if you work with 11-bit values *(as others have mentioned)*, which you haven't stated anywhere. If you really want to parse the hex as an 11-bit signed value, please edit the question and clarify that, so we know you want to work with obscure 11-bit values, and are not just confused as to where the sign bit is located.

Answer (score 4):

To parse a hex string to an 11-bit signed value, you can use the following method.

The algorithm was taken from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#VariableSignExtend) by Sean Eron Anderson.

```
public static int parseElevenBits(String hex) {
    return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16) << 21 >> 21;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(parseElevenBits("400"));
System.out.println(parseElevenBits("401"));
System.out.println(parseElevenBits("7FE"));
System.out.println(parseElevenBits("7FF"));
System.out.println(parseElevenBits("0"));
System.out.println(parseElevenBits("1"));
System.out.println(parseElevenBits("3FE"));
System.out.println(parseElevenBits("3FF"));
```

*Output*

```
-1024
-1023
-2
-1
0
1
1022
1023
```

Comment: @shmosel I actually left that out on purpose, so people would look at the link and learn from there.